# How to show UIAlertController top of the presenting cotroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I have the top view controller is presenting, and I want to show alert controller but it not display. Have any way to do it?

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solved my problem. It so easy, just input the controller we are standing on into the show alertcontroller function below:

```
func showAlerControler(title: String?, message: String, confirmButtonText: String?, cancelButtonText: String?, atController: UIViewController){
    var alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    if let confirmStr = confirmButtonText{
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: confirmStr, style: .Default, handler: { (ACTION) -> Void in

    }))
    }
    if let cancelStr = cancelButtonText{
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancelStr, style: .Default, handler: { (ACTION) -> Void in

        }))
    }
    atController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Don't use **appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)**

And you can standing on any controller to call **showAlerControler** and input **atController** is **self**

Answer (score 1):

(Objective-C)

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"myTitle" message:@"myMessage"
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertVC addAction:[UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction* action) {
                            [alertVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        }
    ]];
[self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("YES tapped")
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancel tapped")
    }

    alert.addAction(yesAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Please also check and make sure that your rootViewController is not nil.

Comment: The **rootViewController** is not nil. But as I said on my question: when the rootViewController is the controller which is presenting then the alert cannot show by call **appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)**

Comment: If your root view controller has presented one view controller, then, you can't use your root view controller to **present** another view controller without dismissing the previous view controller first. Otherwise you'll get a warning like this: `Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fa0eadaa590> on <aa.ViewController: 0x7fa0ead9aa20> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. You should present that alert from the previous view controller instead of the root view controller.